# How can I sort Excel cells in groups?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

[image]

I have something like the following, but over 1000 rows.  Further down some of the blue headers have multiple white inner cells.  Now I know I can do grouping, but if I select row 1 and 2 and group them, when I select rows 3 & 4 and group them, they get added to the group made with 1 & 2.  The only way I was able to somewhat do this was by grouping 3&4, within group the group 1&2 is in. The issue then is that I can only group up to 8 sub-branches in, and well, I have 1000+ rows.  Not sure how else I can do this and all I've been able to find online is about using a helper column, but with 1000+ rows, going through it all making a helper column is also a lengthy process.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a helper column is the most straightforward way to handle. Filter for your headers (assumes they all read yearly, monthly, weekly and that they are unique) and paste them in another location to serve as a lookup table. Add a column next to the pasted headings and add unique numbers that will serve as a grouping value. To the right of your data range, create an if statement to check if the cell value to the left has a match in the look up table and if so, return the number; if there's no match then return the value of the cell above the current cell. Then copy the formula down. When done, copy the helper coulumn and paste values in place. This serves as your grouping column. To the right of this, copy this formula down then copy and paste values in place:

```
=ROW()
```

That will serve as your sort column. This should take less than 5 minutes to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is the EN_WG prefix consistent? If so, you can insert a column (Column A, let's say) to the left. Copy the first B1 to A1, and then put this in A2 and fill down.

> =IF(LEFT(B2,6)="EN_WG_",B2,A1)

If you have a headers in row 1, then you don't have to manually copy the first EN_WG_ over and can start the formula in A2 directly.

This translates your data into a horizontal layout and allows you to sort by your category (Now in Column A).